# Swift CharacterSet subtract

Tags: swift

Why characters1 is not empty?

```
var characters1 = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
let characters2 = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "01234567890")
characters1.subtract(characters2)
print(characters1.isEmpty)
```

Here everything is OK

```
var characters1 = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "9876543210")
let characters2 = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")
characters1.subtract(characters2)
print(characters1.isEmpty)
```

Comment: There are far more decimal digits in the world than just 0...9. As an example "൧" is "MALAYALAM DIGIT ONE", and "৯" is "BENGALI DIGIT NINE"

Comment: [Unicode Characters in the 'Number, Decimal Digit' Category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1408239-decimaldigits) (emphasis mine)

> Informally, this set is the set of all characters used to represent
>   the decimal values 0 through 9. These characters include, for example,
>   **the decimal digits of the Indic scripts** and Arabic.

Therefore, `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` don't only contains "9876543210", they also have numerals from the Indic scripts (and other scripts).

Comment: Also please note that this is not in Swift itself. It's in the Foundation framework. Swift has no `CharacterSet` in the std library.